# Como ir a carpeta principal dentro de una subcarpeta con boton href

Tags: php, html, mysqli

mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer yo para que el href que tengo dentro de mi carpeta login, me redireccione a la carpeta principal.

```html
<hr><p>Principal page? <a href="flore/nosotros.php" title="goback">Go back</a>.</p>
```

la carpeta flore es mi carpeta principal, como puedo yo editar eso para que yo estando en la carpeta login, que esta dentro de flore, me vaya a una pagina de la otra carpeta.

z(subcarpeta dentro de A) A(carpeta grande donde tengo guardado z)(b archivo .php)

Quiero hacer esta función de abajo.

z -->Ab

Ya que el problema que tengo con esto, es que cuando utilizo lo que ya tengo se suma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal, las carpetas *z* y *b* son hermanas e hijas de *A*, entonces prueba bajando un nivel:

```
<a href="../nosotros.php" title="goback">Go back</a>
```

Comment: Me has entendido fenomenal, gracias bro.